# 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 results in a negative number

Tags: java, android, math, long-integer, negative-number

I'm attempting to calculate 30 days by multiplying milliseconds however the result continually ends up being a negative number for the value of days_30  and I'm not sure why.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

CODE SNIPPET:

```
// check to ensure proper time has elapsed
                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext()
                        .getSharedPreferences("DataCountService", 0);
                 long days_30 = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
                 long oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp", 0);
                long newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                 if(newTime - oldTime >= days_30){
```

days_30 value results in: -1702967296

P.S.

```
 double days_30 = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
                 double oldTime = pref.getLong("smstimestamp", 0);
                double newTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                 if(newTime - oldTime >= days_30){
```

Results in a smaller - but still negative number. -1.702967296E9

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12758352/1679863)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are multiplying `ints` together, and overflow occurs because [the maximum integer is `2^31 - 1`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE).  Only after the multiplications does it get converted to a `long`.  Cast the first number as a `long`.

```
long days_30 = (long) 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
```

or use a `long` literal:

```
long days_30 = 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
```

That will force `long` math operations from the start.

Answer (score 2):

```
   long days_30 = 1L * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change your multiplication to `long days_30 = 1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30;`

Answer (score 0):

Java has limitations when it comes to primitive data types.  If your long or double are too big, then it will overflow into a negative number.  Try using the BigInteger class for storing larger numbers.

Check this out:

[How does Java handle integer underflows and overflows and how would you check for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo)

Comment: A `long` is good enough in this case

Comment: If "Computers have limitations when it comes to numbers", then how would BigInteger help?

Comment: If a `double` goes beyond its range, then `POSITIVE_INFINITY` (or `NEGATIVE_INFINITY`) results, not an overflow.

Comment: I'm sorry for the unclear explanation.  Java limits primitive data types.  For example, longs and doubles are 64 bits (excluding over head).  However, if you use a Java object (or a class that extends from Object), the size can as large as the computer's memory is (or whatever the remaining space is before it crashes lol).