# java multiplication between int and longs gives 0

Tags: java, int, type-conversion, long-integer, multiplication

```
private static final int FIRST  = 8;
private static final int SECOND = (4 * 1024 * 1024)/8;
private static final int THIRD = (4 * 1024 * 1024);
private static final long RESULT  = FIRST *SECOND * THIRD;
```

Why is the product of the 3 coming out to be 0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do these two multiplication operations give different results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758338/why-do-these-two-operations-give-different-results)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is the product of the 3 coming out to be 0?

Your multiplication is being done in `int` arithmetic, and it's overflowing, with a result of 0. You're basically doing 2<sup>24</sup> * 2<sup>24</sup>, i.e. 2<sup>48</sup> - and the bottom 32 bits of that results are all 0. The fact that you assign the *result* of the operation to a `long` doesn't change the type used to *perform* the operation.

To perform the arithmetic using 64-bit integer arithmetic, just change an operand to be `long`:

```
private static final long RESULT  = (long) FIRST * SECOND * THIRD;
```

Comment: Oh, so as long as even one operand is of the higher precision each of the operands will be converted to match that, and since in this case my result is long..things will give expected results. Cool..Thanks

Comment: @user1071840: Yes. See section 15.17 of the JLS for details.