# Java giving wrong result

Tags: java

I have a method in a java program here that is giving wrong result on a simple multiplication and I am not sure what's going on. Maybe it's a setting in eclipse that I need to expand -- I just have no idea.

Simple as this: 987,654,321 * 10.  Should obviously be 9,876,543,210. Instead I am getting 1,286,608,618. What in the world? The method is simply reading in characters and adding the tokenized number (not longer than 10 digits) to a list. Everything else works fine but it hates this number for some reason.

```
public void number(char dig, boolean lc){
    int num = Character.getNumericValue(dig);
    if(number == 0){
        number = num;
    }
    else{           
        number = number*10 + num;
    }
    if(lc){
        if(String.valueOf(number).trim().length() <= intLength){
            tokenList.add(number);
            number = 0;
            return;
        }
        else{
        System.out.println("Error in number entry. Invalid or exceeded length: " + number); 
            number = 0; 
            return;
            }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is number coming from?  Also, you should avoid naming that funciton "number"

Comment: What is 2 raised to the 31st power??

Comment: “overflow”. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your value is far outside the range of integer. The following statement:

```
System.out.println(9_876_543_210L);  // This is what you are claiming should have come
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

prints:

```
9876543210
2147483647
```

So, when you do `987654321 * 10`, the value can't fit into an `int`, and thus it overflows, and you get that result.

Alternative? Use `long` type.

---

**See also:**

- [Why do these two multiplication operations give different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12758338/1679863)

Comment: This fixed it. Never would have occurred to me. Will accept your answer as soon as the 10 minute minimum runs out.