# How output changes for a number when multiplying with long?

Tags: java, long-integer

When I multiply `long`s with `L` prefix I get the result `31536000000`.

When I multiply `long`s without `L` prefix I get the result `1471228928`.

How the result getting varies?

I am thinking number exceeds the `int?  range but not sure.

```java
long longWithL = 1000*60*60*24*365L;
long longWithoutL = 1000*60*60*24*365;
System.out.println(longWithL);
System.out.println(longWithoutL);
```

Output:

```
31536000000
1471228928
```

Comment: Yes, an int overflow: positive int goes upto 2^31 ≈ 2*10^9, so 9 digits. Your product 3+3+3+3+3 = 12 digits. Mind that more safe would have been 1000L, as 1000*60*60*24 already reaches 9 digits.

Comment: `int * long = long` in first case. And in second case it multiplies some integers together, converts it to a long and then assigns the result to a `longWithoutL` variable.

Answer (score 2):

A plain number is perceived as `int` by the Java Standard always. If you wish to make the compiler know that the number which is being operated is other than integer type, the postfix letter is required, e.g. `L`, `F`(for floating point numbers, similar idea).

By the by, as an additional information, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` operators' left-hand side has more precedence vis-à-vis its left-hand side's. So, for example, `10L*2*3*4*5` results in type of `long`. To make sure for the mentioned example, the following image can be examined.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it outputs different result because of overflow in Integer Result. when you write `long longWithoutL = 1000*60*60*24*365;`. java read that numbers as Integers. multiplication is going out of the bounds of Integer and java tries to fit it into the Integer. To have Correct output try to use Suffix like `L`, `D`, `F`. same it true if you write 4.676 java assumes that number is `Double` this question already have an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/769963/javas-l-number-long-specification) here and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353529/java-long-assignment-confusing)

Comment: The answer is subject to `=` operator. Normally, `1000*60*60*24*365` results in type of `int`. Since `long`'s capacity is greater than `int`'s, the translation can be done. So, `longWithoutL` variable name can be fallacious, at least for me.

Comment: @snr yes, same here. i just copied his code example.