# Incorrect Multiplication Result

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand why this multiplication results in an incorrect value:

```
long max = (60 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

This should = 5,184,000,000

But in my Java program it = 889,032,704

Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: use unsigned long or long long

Comment: @TejasPatel this question is tagged Java which does not have the types you recommend.

Comment: This has been asked several times over.  Ditto copy of one or more existing questions.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758338/why-do-these-two-multiplication-operations-give-different-results

Comment: Particularly [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12758352/2235132)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All of the values you're multiplying are `int`s so the result is an `int` which is cast to a `long` after overflow has already happened.  Make one of the factors a `long` so that they are multiplied using 64b instructions

Try

```
long max = (60L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L);
```

The `L` suffix specifies that the constant is a `long` value, not an `int` constant.

The [language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) says

> An integer literal is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type `int` (§4.2.1).

and the [section on multiplication](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17) says

> The type of a multiplicative expression is the promoted type of its operands.

and [type promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) of two `int`s leaves them as `int`s:

> Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
> - If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to `double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted to `float`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to `long`.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`

Comment: Thanks Mike.  Your explanation makes perfect sense.

Comment: @punkrocker27ka, This is a common error.  So common that the [Go folk](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) decided to make integer constants arbitrary precision: "Numeric constants represent values of arbitrary precision and do not overflow. ... These requirements apply both to literal constants and to the result of evaluating constant expressions."

Comment: Great :), This work like charm, Great Explanation :)

Answer (score 5):

This is due to integer overflow. Your right-side product is represented as `int` (default type of all operands) and it obliviously can't hold your "long" value.

Just make the first factor of your product `long`, either as long constant `60L`, as in Mike's answer, or cast it explicitly `(long) 60` :

```
long max = (long) 60 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
```

and you will get what you expect.