# modulo gives wrong result for big number in Java

Tags: java, biginteger, modulo

look at the below Java Code :

```java
        long a = (long) 10e9+7;
        long b = (a * a);

        System.out.println("b is " + b);
        System.out.println("b%a is " + (b%a));

        System.out.println();


        BigInteger A = BigInteger.valueOf((long) 10e9+7);
        BigInteger B = A.multiply(A);


        System.out.println("B is " + B.longValue());
        System.out.println("B.mod(A) is " + B.mod(A));
```

Output:

```
b is 7766279771452241969
b%a is 6015846137   ///->> why ?? overflow 

B is 7766279771452241969 //// -> should not overflow 
B.mod(A) is 0
```

I was expecting % to give 0 in above case. But it gives some other numbers for the %

Comment: Can you show the value of `B`instead of `b`? I suspect overflow while calculating `b`.

Comment: You are clearly dealing with integer (or long) overflow. It should be obvious that 10e9+7 (which is 10000000007 in other notation) multiplied with itself will not result in a number that starts with 776.....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Incorrect Multiplication Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299070/incorrect-multiplication-result)

Comment: Did you mean `1.0e9+7`? That would actually work, since that number squared fits in a `long`. But `10e9+7` squared doesn't. Note that `10e9 == 1.0e10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a * a` overflows the value of `Long.MAX_VALUE`. As Benoit suggested in his comment, you're printing `b` twice. The value of `B` is not `7766279771452241969` but `100000000140000000049`.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, `long b = a * a` overflows, since it should have the value `100.000.000.140.000.000.049` and it's greater than the max value of a signed long (`2^63 - 1 = 9.223.372.036.854.775.807`).

Secondly, I think it should be said that there are some differences between the two operation that you've used. As stated in the comments of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/90247/10301322), java has the [**reminder** operator `%`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) and does not provide a **modulo** operator or a function, like `BigInteger` does. Those are two slightly different things.

Mathematically if you want the result of *c*, given as *c = a (mod b)*, it will be a number such that *1 < c < b* (e.g. `4 (mod 3) = 1`). Consequently, if *b = a * a*, then *b (mod a) = a * a (mod a) = 0*.
If you want to read more about it, I suggest you to take a look at [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).

The java reminder operator `%`, gives the reminder of the division (considering `n % d`), which has *n* as the numerator and *d* as the denominator. When mixing positive and negative numbers, there could be some inconsistencies with *n (mod d)*, since

> [mod and remainder are actually semantically different operations](https://therenegadecoder.com/blog/java-has-a-remainder-operator-not-a-mod-operator/#the-blurry-line-between-mod-and-remainder)

In conclusion, if you want to use modulo, you should rely on the [functions provided from BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), otherwise use the reminder operator.
I also suggest [this reading](https://therenegadecoder.com/blog/java-has-a-remainder-operator-not-a-mod-operator/) that explain the difference between modulus and reminder.