# Ints and Longs multiplication gives different answers

Tags: java

Why does `ci1` contain the wrong value

Whats going on when you multiply three int and convert to long?

```
public class integers{

  public static void main(String []args){

    int im1 = 12*5280;
    long ci1;

    long im2 = 12*5280;
    long ci2;

    ci1 = im1 * im1 * im1;
    ci2= im2 * im2* im2;
    System.out.println(im1+" "+ci1);
    System.out.println(im2 +" "+ci2);
  }
}
```

Output is

```
63360 1507852288

63360 254358061056000
```

the second line is the correct answer and 63360 fts easily into an int

Comment: I think a better duplicate target is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758338.

Comment: Probably they have different types, which probably have different properties ...

Comment: @pkpnd Duely noted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The max value an integer can hold [is roughly 2 billion (2,147,483,648)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE). The result of your multiplication is roughly 200 trillion (254,358,061,056,000). This is a case of [integer overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001836/how-does-java-handle-integer-underflows-and-overflows-and-how-would-you-check-fo).

`int * int * int` will give you an integer before it's widened to a long and assigned to the long variable.

Comment: Ahhh, the answer I get is the overflowed int assigned the the long. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The multiplication is performed using the types of the operands – the type you are assigning the result to has nothing to do with it. So when you multiply those `int`s, there will be an overflow since `254358061056000` does not fit inside an `int`. Only then is the result cast to a `long`.

Answer (score 1):

In fact,
before assignment : `ci1 =` which is a long,  java handle the right part,
where it's manipulate `int`.
`int * int` return an `int`

As the value you try to get is a `long` you need explicit it

You could tell java that you want to manipulate long

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int im1 = 12 * 5280;
    long ci1;

    long im2 = 12 * 5280;
    long ci2;

    ci1 = (long)im1 * (long)im1 * (long)im1;
    ci2 = im2 * im2 * im2;
    System.out.println(im1 + " " + ci1);
    System.out.println(im2 + " " + ci2);
}
```